# Variables inside string variables in devops

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-devops

Is there any way to deep replace variables in connection strings?  I have dbhost, dbusername, dbpassword in a Library Group.

I have a config transformation `Web.alpha.config`:

`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=$(dbHost) ..." xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />`

I want the `dbhost` variable to be resolved at Release and update the variable inside the string.

It works if I create a variable called `DefaultConnection` with a value of `Server=$(dbHost)` and then another variable called `dbHost`.  The problem with that is that it's a real pain to deal with outside of Rider.

Comment: So you want to find an easier way to replace the variable in connectionString, right?

Comment: Yes.  Maybe even scrapping this whole plan and doing something easier is possible.

Comment: I read some of the documentation and tried to look for similar issues these days. As of this time, however, your approach is probably the simplest way to replace the variable.